# Автоматически обрезать большие логи в /var/log

Tags: ubuntu, логирование, файловая-система

Столкнулись недавно с проблемой - инстанс игровой серверный заспамил лог файл и забил весь диск.

Ошибка в Unity3d нативной сетке, повлиять на это не можем.

Некоторые приложения сами следят за такими вещами (supervisord и т.п.). Но вот что делать в случае, когда приложение не следит за размером своего лога? Есть какая-нибудь автоматизированная тулза, которая будет резать слишком толстые лог файлы? `/dev/null` не предлагать.

Comment: logrotate . . .

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/437592/416190